# WCF Rest service throwing http error 404 when accessing the link via https but working perfectly fine with http

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis-6

I have a WCF REST Service hosted in IIS 6.0 (.NET framwork 4). This service is being called by a JAVA service.
Now when the Java service accesses this service via http it works fine but the time it calls using https then error 404 is returned

*"Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed"*

I have verified that the SSL certificate is installed and there are other two serviceshosted in IIS which seem unaffected.

Now I checked that I am able to access the .svc file via the https domain.
HTTPS:.......service alias/service.svc  <-- this works fine

The issue happens when a method is called inside the service.
HTTPS:.......service alias/service.svc/service method name  <-- throws error

Now I checked on another server it works fine using https. So my guess is there is not much wrong with the code.
So can you guys tell me if there is anything that I am missing? I need this service to run on https in this server as well.

This service communicates via POST while the other two services which seem unaffected use GET. Not sure if this is of any significance though.

Comment: Are you able to access the service from a .net app via https? Also is the certificate a self signed certificate?

Comment: No it is not working from any .Net app as well. Same issue. It is a trusted certificate

Comment: You would consider enabling tracing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on your service to get an exact reason on why the request is failing. It would be more helpful if you can provide your config and  some sample code to help you out more.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are missing something in your web.config.  You will need to either change your default endpoint to support encryption or create a new endpoint doing so.

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding>
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: But if it indeed is an issue with web config should it not also fail in another server?

Comment: But the same code works on another server. So would it really be a config issue?

Comment: IMPORTANT: If you just upgraded to .Net Framework 4.5 and you have the problem described by Jay, your original web.config file probably never had the <security mode="Transport" /> in it to start with and it worked perfectly fine until you installed 4.5. Clearly 4.5 has broken something. Thanks a hell of a lot for the millionth time Microsoft for breaking stuff with your updates. The frustration and hours spent trying to solve this is just another reason to ditch Microsoft.

Answer (score -1):

If you are getting a 404, it has got nothing to do with certificate or https. Just check if the method is configured properly i.e. `[WebInvoke]` in your service contracts has properly mentioned the methods name.